# How to scaffold/structure folders building a full-stack MEAN application?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, yeoman, mean-stack, scaffolding

I'm planning on building a website using MEAN stack. Now I'm confused with how I should structure out my folders in a MVC way.

I've investigated in some Yeoman generators, [generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) and [generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack).

- How are these two different?
- Is there additional folders required when building a full-stack application?
- Does the Angular controllers represent the C in MVC?
- Where should I put my Model files?

Examples provided would be great.

Comment: I would recommend reading this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure for how to structor an angular app. An express application is the simple and straight forward part of the MEAN stack (so is Angular after you get around the ideas).
Any way I wont recommend  using generators if you are a beginner - It makes you lazy about thinking "why" and "how" things should by on your app.

Comment: Hey @Shikloshi thanks for the link, very useful. But I've seen so many other structures and pretty confused which to follow. Also very worried how to set up Grunt with self-defined folder structure.